# Using Registry in StructureMap to create a pluggable architechture

Tags: c#, architecture, structuremap, ravendb

I have a web project and I want it to work with ravendb and ravendb-embedded.
So this is how I think I should solve it.

Two projects, MvcRavendb and MvcRavendb-Embedded where the two projects references two different nuget packages, one for ravendb and one for ravendb embedded.

In my core project I have an interface IDocumentStoreInitializer which has one method, IDocumentStore InitializeDocumentStore()

MvcRavenDb and MvcRavenDb-Embedded has one class like this

```
public class RegisterRavenDb : IDocumentStoreInitializer {
    public IDocumentStore InitializeDocumentStore() {
        return new DocumentStore OR EmbeddableDocumentStore();
    }
}
```

Then I have a class that registers the concrete implementation like this

```
public class RavenRegistry : Registry {
    public RavenRegistry() {
        For<IDocumentStoreInitializer>().Use<RegisterRavenDb>();
    }
}
```

So far so good but then I have bootstrapper that configures structuremap like this

```
public class Bootstrapper {
    public static IContainer Initialize() {
       ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
       {
          // here I want to use the registered concrete implmentaiton of IDocumentStore
          var documentStore = new DocumentStore { ConnectionStringName = "RavenDB" };

          documentStore.Initialize();
       }
    }
 }
```

So how can I tell structuremap to use InitializeDocumentStore from the RavenRegistry class?
Maybe I have missed something or I'm taking the wrong approach here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the EmbeddableDocumentStore instance, using the connection string, you can control whatever it will be embedded or server/client.

Comment: Do I need to add the nuget package for both RavenDB and RavenDB-Embedded? When I try to create an EmbeddableDocumentStore with connectionstring Url = http://localhost:8080 it returns null.

Comment: It seems like the embeddabledocumentstore cannot be initialized with connectionstringname? If I use Url or DataDirectory directly when creating the instance it works.

Answer (score 0):

This should do as you wish. In **OnCreation** the ConnectionString can be set, too.

```
        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
        {
            // here I want to use the registered concrete implmentaiton of IDocumentStore
            x.Scan(scan =>
                       {
                           scan.TheCallingAssembly();
                           scan.AssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory();
                           scan.LookForRegistries();
                       });

            x.For<IDocumentStore>().Use(c =>
                c.GetInstance<IDocumentStoreInitializer>().
                    InitializeDocumentStore()).OnCreation<IDocumentStore>(z => z.Initialize());
        });
```